# Не понятка с работой клавиши enter javascript

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго времени суток есть необходимось, что бы при нажатии на кнопу <kbd>Enter</kbd> отрабатывался клик по определеному `id`, код  Javascript  реальный:

```js
$(window).keypress(function(event) {
  event.preventdefault()
  var keyCode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode :
    event.charCode ? event.charCode :
    event.which ? event.which : void 0;
  var input = $('#form_search_tel input').val();
  //if pressed "Enter" key
  if (keyCode == 13 && input) {
    $("#ptable").click();
    $("#ptablelv").click();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="ptable">click</p>
<p id="ptablelv">click</p>
```

Проблема в том, что при нажатии на <kbd>Enter</kbd> страница перегружается и потом `click` отрабатывается. То так не должно быть т.е. страница не должна перегружаться а `click` должен отрабатываться. Подскажите как можно избавиться от перезагрузки. К клику на `<p>` привязан Ajax.

Comment: Хорошо подскажи как мне организовать что бы при клике на enter отрабатывал клик по двум ссылкам ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Нажатие на Enter при фокусе в input? Если ДА то когда в форме (`<form></form>`) есть только один `<input type="text" />` и сабмит `<input type="submit" />` по нажатию на enter внутри этого `input` форма отправится автоматически это стандартное поведение браузера. И "превентить" уже нужно не только `keypress` но и `submit` у события формы.

2) Событие вешайте на `$(document)`

3) Триггерите таким образом `$('selector').trigger('event');`

4) Проверьте мб где-то уже перехватываются события до Вашего кода и возвращается `false`

Comment: Это не форма там аяксом в се прикручено и отправляеться при клике на <p>. от формы там только input.